# Why is my controller sending the content type "application/octet-stream"?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I have a REST controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@ResponseBody
public HttpEntity<GreetingResource> greetingResource(@RequestParam(value = "message", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String message) {
    GreetingResource greetingResource = new GreetingResource(String.format(TEMPLATE, message));
    greetingResource.add(linkTo(methodOn(AdminController.class).greetingResource(message)).withSelfRel());
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    return new ResponseEntity<GreetingResource>(greetingResource, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying hard to specify the content type returned by the controller.

It is accessed with a REST client:

```
public String getGreetingMessage() {
    String message;
    try {
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = Common.createAuthenticationHeaders("stephane" + ":" + "mypassword");
        ResponseEntity<GreetingResource> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("/admin/greeting", GreetingResource.class, httpHeaders);
        GreetingResource greetingResource = responseEntity.getBody();
        message = greetingResource.getMessage();
    } catch (HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
        message = "The GET request FAILED with the message being not readable: " + e.getMessage();
    } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
        message = "The GET request FAILED with the HttpStatusCode: " + e.getStatusCode() + "|" + e.getStatusText();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        message = "The GET request FAILED " + ExceptionUtils.getFullStackTrace(e);
    }
    return message;
}
```

The http headers are created by a utility:

```
static public HttpHeaders createAuthenticationHeaders(String usernamePassword) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    byte[] encodedAuthorisation = Base64.encode(usernamePassword.getBytes());
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + new String(encodedAuthorisation));
    return headers;
}
```

The web security configuration and code work fine. I make sure of this using a mockMvc based integration test which succeeds.

The only test that fails is the one based on the REST template:

```
@Test
public void testGreeting() throws Exception {
    mockServer.expect(requestTo("/admin/greeting")).andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET)).andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.OK));
    String message = adminRestClient.getGreetingMessage();
    mockServer.verify();
    assertThat(message, allOf(containsString("Hello"), containsString("World")));
}
```

The exception given in the Maven build console output is:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: (a string containing "Hello" and a string containing "World")
got: "The GET request FAILED org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException : Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.resource.GreetingR esource] and content type [application/octet-stream]\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverte rExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtract or.java:107)
```

I'm using the Spring Framework 3.2.2.RELEASE version and the Spring Security 3.1.4.RELEASE version on the Java 1.6 version.

At first, I had a bare bone REST template:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    return restTemplate;
}
```

I have now added to it, hoping it would help:

```
private static final Charset UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();        
    mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("application", "json", UTF8)));
    messageConverters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);

    Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    jaxb2Marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(new Class[] {
        GreetingResource.class
    });
    MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingHttpMessageConverter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(jaxb2Marshaller, jaxb2Marshaller);
    messageConverters.add(marshallingHttpMessageConverter);

    messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    stringHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("text", "plain", UTF8)));
    messageConverters.add(stringHttpMessageConverter);
    messageConverters.add(new BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
    messageConverters.add(new AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter());
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    return restTemplate;
}
```

But it didn't change anything and the exception remains the same.

My understanding is that, it is not the REST template that needs any specific JSON configuration, but rather, that, for some reason, my controller is spitting out some application/octet-stream content type instead of some application/json content type.

Any clue?

Some additional information...

The admin rest client bean in the web test configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebTestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public AdminRestClient adminRestClient() {
        return new AdminRestClient();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();        
        mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("application", "json", UTF8)));
        messageConverters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);

        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        jaxb2Marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(new Class[] {
            Greeting.class
        });
        MarshallingHttpMessageConverter marshallingHttpMessageConverter = new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter(jaxb2Marshaller, jaxb2Marshaller);
        messageConverters.add(marshallingHttpMessageConverter);

        messageConverters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
        messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
        StringHttpMessageConverter stringHttpMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
        stringHttpMessageConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(new MediaType("text", "plain", UTF8)));
        messageConverters.add(stringHttpMessageConverter);
        messageConverters.add(new BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter());
        messageConverters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());
        messageConverters.add(new AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter());
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
        return restTemplate;
    }

}
```

The base test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration( classes = { ApplicationConfiguration.class, WebSecurityConfig.class, WebConfiguration.class, WebTestConfiguration.class })
@Transactional
public abstract class AbstractControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Autowired  
    protected RestTemplate restTemplate;  

    protected MockRestServiceServer mockServer;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    }

}
```

The web init class:

```
public class WebInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebInit.class);

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        registerListener(servletContext);

        registerDispatcherServlet(servletContext);

        registerJspServlet(servletContext);

        createSecurityFilter(servletContext);
    }

    private void registerListener(ServletContext servletContext) {
        // Create the root application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = createContext(ApplicationConfiguration.class, WebSecurityConfig.class);

        // Set the application display name
        appContext.setDisplayName("LearnInTouch");

        // Create the Spring Container shared by all servlets and filters
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(appContext));
    }

    private void registerDispatcherServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = createContext(WebConfiguration.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(webApplicationContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);

        Set<String> mappingConflicts = dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        if (!mappingConflicts.isEmpty()) {
          for (String mappingConflict : mappingConflicts) {
            logger.error("Mapping conflict: " + mappingConflict);
          }
          throw new IllegalStateException(
              "The servlet cannot be mapped to '/'");
        }
    }

    private void registerJspServlet(ServletContext servletContext) {
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext createContext(final Class... modules) {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(modules);
        return appContext;
    }

    private void createSecurityFilter(ServletContext servletContext) {
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic springSecurityFilterChain = servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
        springSecurityFilterChain.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }

}
```

The web configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableEntityLinks
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.thalasoft.learnintouch.rest.controller")
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        PageableArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableArgumentResolver();
        resolver.setFallbackPageable(new PageRequest(1, 10));
        resolvers.add(new ServletWebArgumentResolverAdapter(resolver));
        super.addArgumentResolvers(resolvers);
    }

}
```

The application configuration is empty for now:

```
@Configuration
@Import({ ApplicationContext.class })
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // Declare "application" scope beans here, that is, beans that are not only used by the web context

}
```

Comment: `mockServer` is a `MockMvc` instance?

Comment: Yes, it is instantiated in a base class with a: this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).addFilters(this.springSecurityFilterChain).build();

Comment: I want to see the initialization of each object used in your `testGreeting` method. I don't think the request is going where you think it's going.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis

Here is the base test class:
`code`
@Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

 @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;
 
 @Autowired  
 protected RestTemplate restTemplate;  
 
 protected MockRestServiceServer mockServer;
 
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    }
`code`
Is that what you were asking for ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. But don't post it in comments, you can edit your question and add it there. Add also your context configuration while you are at it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had my doubts before, but now that you've posted everything, here's what's up. Assuming the `RestTemplate` object you use in your `getGreetingMessage()` method is the same as the one declared in the `@Bean` method, the problem starts here

```
this.mockServer = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
```

This call overwrites the default `ClientHttpRequestFactory` object that the `RestTemplate` object uses internally with a mock. In your `getGreetingMessage()` method, this call

```
ResponseEntity<GreetingResource> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("/admin/greeting", GreetingResource.class, httpHeaders);
```

doesn't actually go through the network. The `RestTemplate` uses the mocked `ClientHttpRequestFactory` to create a fake `ClientHttpRequest` which produces a fake `ClientHttpResponse` which doesn't have a `Content-Type` header. When the `RestTemplate` looks at the `ClientHttpResponse` to determine its `Content-Type` and doesn't find one, it assumes `application/octet-stream` by default.

So, your controller isn't setting the content type because your controller is never hit. The `RestTemplate` is using a default content type for your response because it is mocked and doesn't actually contain one.

---

From your comments:

> I wonder if I understand what the mock server is testing. I understand
>   it is to be used in acceptance testing scenario. Is it supposed to hit
>   the controller at all ?

The javadoc for [`MockRestServiceServer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html) states:

> **Main entry point for client-side REST testing.** Used for tests that 
>   involve direct or indirect (through client code)
>   use of the `RestTemplate`. Provides a way to set up fine-grained
>   expectations on the requests that will be performed through the
>   `RestTemplate` and a way to define the responses to send back removing
>   the need for an actual running server.

In other words, it's as if your application server didn't exist. So you could throw any expectations (and actual return values) you wanted and test whatever happens from the client side. So you aren't testing your server, you are testing your client.

Are you sure you aren't looking for [`MockMvc`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/MockMvc.html), which is

> **Main entry point for server-side Spring MVC test support.**

which you can setup to actually use your `@Controller` beans in an integration environment. You aren't actually sending HTTP request, but the `MockMvc` is simulating how they would be sent and how your server would respond.

Comment: Thanks. You are spot on. I did the almost same thing with a mock mvc for integration testing and I could feed it with my context: this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).addFilters(this.springSecurityFilterChain).build(); So I guess I need to do the same for the mock server if that is an option.

Comment: I wonder if I understand what the mock server is testing. I understand it is to be used in acceptance testing scenario. Is it supposed to hit the controller at all ?

Comment: I cannot define the rest template in the test base class @Before method as it is used by the AdminRestClient class. So I have to define the rest template in a web test configuration. I noticed I could feed the rest template with the application context, as in:         this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).addFilters(this.springSecurityFilterChain).build(); RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new MockMvcClientHttpRequestFactory(this.mockMvc));
But this did not change the exception and the error message remained the exact same.

Comment: @StephaneEybert I tried to clarify in an edit to my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Thank you buddy. Now you made it clear. I thought the mock server was also a way to test the server, just like the mock mvc. I guess I will not use the mock server for now. I'm already using the mock mvc and it works perfectly fine. Thanks for the clarification !

Comment: @StephaneEybert You're welcome. Consider upvoting and/or accepting answers to your questions that were helpful. See the little checkmark under the answer score.

Answer (score 1):

It is bug in `MockHttpServletRequest` and I will try to describe it.
Issue in tracker https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-11308#comment-97327
Fixed in version 4.0.1

#### Bug

When `DispatcherServlet` looking for method to invoke it using some RequestConditions. One of them is `ConsumesRequestCondition`. The following is a piece of code:

```
@Override
    protected boolean matchMediaType(HttpServletRequest request) throws HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException {
        try {
            MediaType contentType = StringUtils.hasLength(request.getContentType()) ?
                    MediaType.parseMediaType(request.getContentType()) :
                    MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM;
            return getMediaType().includes(contentType);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            throw new HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException(
                    "Can't parse Content-Type [" + request.getContentType() + "]: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

We are interested in piece `request.getContentType()`. There request is `MockHttpServletRequest`. Let's look on method getContentType():

```
public String getContentType() {
    return this.contentType;
}
```

It just return value of `this.contentType`. **It does not return a value from the header**! And `this.contentType` is always NULL. Then `contentType` in `matchMediaType` methos will be always `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM`.

#### Solution

I have tried many ways but have found only one that works.

- Create package `org.springframework.test.web.client` in your test directory.
- Create copy of `org.springframework.test.web.client.MockMvcClientHttpRequestFactory` but rename it. For example rename to `FixedMockMvcClientHttpRequestFactory`.
- Find line:

  ```
  MvcResult mvcResult = MockMvcClientHttpRequestFactory.this.mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
  ```
- Replace it with code:

  ```
  MvcResult mvcResult = FixedMockMvcClientHttpRequestFactory.this.mockMvc.perform(new RequestBuilder() {
      @Override
      public MockHttpServletRequest buildRequest(ServletContext servletContext) {
          MockHttpServletRequest request = requestBuilder.buildRequest(servletContext);
          request.setContentType(request.getHeader("Content-Type"));
          return request;
      }
  }).andReturn();
  ```
- And register your ClientHttpReque

  ```
  @Bean
  public ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory(MockMvc mockMvc) {
      return new FixedMockMvcClientHttpRequestFactory(mockMvc);
  }
  ```

I know that it is not beautiful solution but it works fine.