# Different content type for the same request

Tags: http, request, http-headers, mime-types, endpoint

I use an extra call to the 3rd party server, and its response content type changes from time to time.
For one connection I get `application/json` (that is what I expect) but another time I get the `application/octet-stream` with the same request. The url is always same and expected response size isn't big.
Let's say I call `https://sideapp.co.uk/symbolname/1/hour/date1/date2`

How can it be explained? I don't know which language they use on there backend side. I've only found the one possible explanation for Java here: [Why is my controller sending the content type "application/octet-stream"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792160/why-is-my-controller-sending-the-content-type-application-octet-stream)

From my side I use Flux `WebClient` for connection but I get the same behavior with pure browser call as well.